# How to add multiple queries in one search in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

## Need your assistance to add below queries in one query ..
First Query:-

```
(index=abc OR index=def  AND index!=ghi AND index!=jkl AND index!=mno AND index!=pqr) 
| eval result=case(blocked=="0","Total Detection",blocked=="1","Total Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Total Detection",RuleAction=="Block","Total Blocked")  
| stats count by result
```

## Second Query :-

```
index=abc  AND Category=* AND index!=ghi AND index!=jkl AND index!=mno AND index!=pqr 
    | eval result=case(blocked=="0","Allowed",blocked=="1","Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Allowed",RuleAction=="Block","Blocked")
    | chart count by index, result usenull=f | append [search ( index=def  AND index!=ghi AND index!=jkl AND index!=mno AND index!=pqr)  
    | eval result=case(blocked=="0","Allowed",blocked=="1","Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Allowed",RuleAction=="Block","Blocked")  
    | chart count by index, result usenull=f]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, since `index=...` is unique, there is not reason to add the `index!=...` clauses. Data in Splunk can only exist in a single index (with a single sourcetype).

So your first SPL should read:

```
(index=abc OR index=def) (blocked=* OR RuleAction=*)
| eval result=case(blocked=="0","Total Detection",blocked=="1","Total Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Total Detection",RuleAction=="Block","Total Blocked")
| stats count by result
```

You second SPL should read:

```
index=abc Category=* (blocked=* OR RuleAction=*)
| eval result=case(blocked=="0","Allowed",blocked=="1","Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Allowed",RuleAction=="Block","Blocked")
```

note: `| chart count by index, result usenull=f` is ***only*** going to list `abc` for your index, since that's the only place data is coming from ... probably not an especially *useful* `chart` command here :)

```
| append
    [ search index=def (blocked=* OR RuleAction=*)
    | eval result=case(blocked=="0","Allowed",blocked=="1","Blocked",blocked=="2","Would have Dropped",RuleAction=="Allow","Allowed",RuleAction=="Block","Blocked")
    ]
```

But why do the `eval`s in the second SPL, since they're instantly being thrown away by `chart`?

This would be much simpler:

```
((index=abc Category=*) OR index=def) (blocked=* OR RuleAction=*)
| chart count by index, result usenull=f
```

But what are you *actually* trying to accomplish with the theoretical SPL?

As it stands ... you're going to get a two-item `chart` indicating counts from two indices.

Comment: thanks @warren .. below are the answers :- index!= required because we want to exclude some indexes.. evel command is used because we want blocked 0 and ruleaction =allowed under same value as "Allowed " you said its true that we are getting only first index value in second query so looking for your support on this

Comment: @supriya - you do not need the `index!=...` clauses. All *other* indices are excluded when you put `index=...`